# I keep getting a segmentation fault here. Been at this for 4 hours

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I really need some help here because I have been trying to find a solution to this for hours and nothing works.

I have these two structs:

```
typedef struct NODE {
    char* line;
    int count;
    struct NODE *left, *right;
} NODE;

typedef struct BST {
    NODE *root;
} BST;
```

And these lines of code which appear suspiscious:

```
if (iflag == 0) {
    char curr_string[300];
    BST binary_tree;

    //fpointer_in = fopen(filename_in, "r");

    //while (!feof(fpointer_in)) {

        //fgets(curr_string, 300, fpointer_in);
        addTreeNode("Hello There!", binary_tree.root); // Adds the node to the binary tree.

    //}
    NODE *cpy = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    cpy->line = calloc(25, sizeof(char));

    cpy->count = 0;
    cpyNode(cpy, binary_tree.root);

    free(cpy);
    free(binary_tree.root);
    //printf("%s\n", cpy->line);
    //free(binary_tree.root);
    //fclose(fpointer_in);
}
```

This is the addTreeNode function:

```
void addTreeNode(char* line_string, NODE* root) {

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = calloc(25, sizeof(char)); // 25 is a test var.
        root->line = calloc(25, sizeof(char)); // 25 is a test variable.
        strcpy(root->line, line_string);
        root->count = 0;    
    }
    else {
        NODE *add_node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        add_node->line = calloc(25, sizeof(char)); // 25 is a test variable.
        strcpy(add_node->line, line_string);

        while (root != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(line_string, root->line) < 0 && root->left == NULL) {
                //cpyNode(node_ptr->left, add_node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The if block in the addTreeNode function has been tested but I have yet to test the else block. Regardless, it is never used so I don't think it's an issue.

The issue here is that I am getting a segmentation faule BEFORE the program even reaches main. When I comment out the cpyNode(cpy, binary_tree.root); statement, then it works. I then proceeded to comment out the entire cpyNode funcition minus the first line. I figured out that the first line is giving me a segmentation fault and I can't figure out why. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something?  You've narrowed down the problem to a single line in the `cpyNode()` function, but you never post the `cpyNode()` function itself?

Comment: How can you be getting a segfault before reaching `main`? Is your testing at fault? BTW love the "braces art" at the bottom of the code.

Comment: "BEFORE the program even reaches main". When someone makes that particular claim about a C program, it usually means they don't understand that stdout is line buffered. Post a _minimal_ but _complete_ program that _still shows the problem_. Otherwise we're just guessing, and it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @WeatherVane *How can you be getting a segfault before reaching main?* It is possible - wrong linker file and for example .data segment in the RO memory. But it is not the case here of course

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, and has been since Dennis and Ken made their first C compiler work in the early 70s.

Comment: And you should always check the return value from `malloc()` et al.

Comment: @WeatherVane The "Braces art" is because I was editing the code in UNIX. I had to open the source file in Visual Studio to upload it here.

Answer (score 2):

You may have other errors, but these are problems you need to address:

```
if(iflag == 0){
    char curr_string[300];
    BST binary_tree;
```

Here, `binary_tree` is uninitialized.

```
        addTreeNode("Hello There!", binary_tree.root);
        //Adds the node to the binary tree.
```

You expect this call to add a node to the tree, but you are passing the uninitialized `root` member in by value, and so the pointer will retain its uninitialized state after the function call returns.

You should modify your `addTreeNode` function to accept a pointer to a `BST`, and pass the address of `binary_tree` to the function.

Comment: Man I am such an idiot! Thanks for the help. The reason as to why I didnt put more code was because the rest of it was pretty much just an empty framework. Though I think I could've posted the cpyNode function :/. About passing a BST pointer though, is it safe to reference the members of the node as (BST pointer)->(Node pointer)->(member)? In any case in which you have to access a member of the head node of the BST, is there a way to reference it so that it is more easily readable and safe?